# How can I make it so that manual download and install of modules is not required by another user running the program?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, module

```
import x
import y  #importing random modules to be used by the program

#...further code
```

How do I make it like the popular apps today that don't require manual download and install of modules, because, it is not necessary the user might have them?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to that question is [Dockers](https://www.docker.com/) you make a container that include everything from the OS to the required modules, then share it with the code, the user will only need to run this container and everything will work perfectly.

Comment: Is it possible to go further and include in the Docker an installer of the programming language interpretor/compiler or something so that the user doesn't even have to do THAT themselves?